# Map column data with composite foreign key in another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, composite-key

I have two hiberate mappings,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_INFO")
public class Product  implements Serializable, Persistable<CustomerPK> {

      @EmbedableId
      private ProductPK cpk;
      @Column(name="tokenNo")
      private String tokenNo; //Getters and setters as usual

}
```

**CustomerPK.java**

```
 @Embeddable
 public class ProductPK implements Serializable{ 

  private String companyId;
  private String productId; //With these two columns I have created PK for PRoduct


 }
```

Now I want to map `tokenNo` from `Product` table into another  `Customer` table.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "CUSTOMER_INFO")
  public class Customer  implements Serializable, Persistable<CustomerPK> {

    @Column(name="product_id")
    private String productId; 
    @Column(name="companyId")
    private String companyId;


    private String tokenNo; // I want to map this column in Product column with companyId+productId
  }
```

I need a way to map that column with `(companyId + productId )` as Foreign Key in `Product` class.

Please help anyway to do that in Spring JPA, Hibernate.

**In Summary (in JDBC words):**

> When I query `Customer` Entity I want to have `tokenNo` column with data (by fetching from `Product` table with `productId + companyId` combination).
>   if Not Hibernate normally I should query product table separately to get the `tokenNo` for the given `productId` & `companyId` in `Customer` table.

is there any way I can do that without doing as above in hibernate & Spring JPA.

Comment: Why not make proper associations like `@OneToOne`?

Comment: how would I do that ?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html